# BGE - how to keep child off, and pose for armature?

Tags: game-engine, rigging, armature

I have a two problems at the start with BGE. In my scene there are two **metarigs** (rigged and skinned) with objects, which they interact.

When I start BGE first - one metarig go into rest pose, but the second metarig standing in pose normal

[image]

Second - objects not keep they "child off":

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just re-parent the first metarig - all you have to do is press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.